# Undefined Cookie Variable

Tags: php, function, variables, cookies

I a have function that saves an information using a cookie. The problem is, when the webpage loads for the first time i got the error undefined variable "pagination_pos"...How will i set a temporary value of this cookie as blank first so that i can prevent this error..Here is the function:

```
    function getPaginationPos(){
if (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page'])){
setcookie('pagination_pos',$_REQUEST['page'],time() + 86400);
return $_REQUEST['page'];
} else {
return ($_COOKIE['pagination_pos']!='' ? $_COOKIE['pagination_pos'] : 1);
}

}
```

I get the undefined variable at line 6

Comment: Is there any code before this? Or are the line numbers correct here?

Comment: @RyanSmith it would have to be that line. The variable that throws the error is called "pagination_pos", which is only referenced on the 6th line shown here.

Comment: @David Undefined superglobals don't throw errors on my configuration. They only return NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error shows up because you are attempting to test and return a variable that has not been initialized.

The recommended solution is to use [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/isset), rather than comparing it to an empty string:

```
return (isset($_COOKIE["pagination_pos"]) ? $_COOKIE["pagination_pos"] : 1);
```

You should also note that this error only appears because you have PHP setup to display [`E_NOTICE`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) errors. You can disable that functionality if you wish, though it is "recommended during development."

---

[**This question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index) has been dubbed the "General Reference Question" for this type of error. You can find some really detailed explanations [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index).

Comment: Thanks @David...I should have thought about isset()...Im sorry im still learning more on web development...Now my pagination is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

If the Cookie is not set - you shouldn't "return" it - you should use this

```
     } else {
     return NULL;
     }
```